# How to implement a stack that waits until element comes to make pop

Tags: c#, .net, stack, observablecollection, observable

My problem is different from what I'll describe, but the essence is analogical.

Let's consider a `stack`. A stack has method `pop()`. This method removes the element from the top and returns it.

#### Problem

When there are no elements in the stack, *do not throw an exception*. Instead, wait until an element can be popped (i.e. when a new element is pushed).

I'm brainstorming this for a few hours and here are some ideas that came to my mind:

- TPL Dataflow
- Reactive Extensions
- `SpinWait.SpinUntil()`

I'm not sure if these are good approaches to the problem, but it smells like *observable*.

How to approach it?

Goal: popping is consumed within `Parallel.ForEach`. When resource is available, it should be returned as soon as possible.

Comment: `BlockingCollection` in  System.Collections.Concurrent; sounds like it does what you want. it has a `GetConsumingEnumerable()` that when used with a foreach loop gets elements when they are present and waits when empty. also these are thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need a queue with commands (such as `pop()`).

When there are no elements in the stack, the `pop()` command would not execute and instead stay in the queue.

Once something is inserted into the stack, the command interpreter will check if it can execute the command (`pop()` in your case) and then execute it.

You can use an `async` pattern to notify you if `stack` changes, on account of which the interpreter would execute a command. This way you can avoid polling to check if stack state has changed.

`Observable Collection` also seems like a nice bet.